# Как в WPF добавить строку в таблицу из MS Access?

Tags: база-данных, wpf, access

Имеем WPF проект, который работает получает и записывает данные в MS Access.
На первой форме находится ListView с отображение таблицы из БД. Во второй форме пользователь вводит данные строки, которая добавляется таблицу из БД.

Вопрос в следующем:

Как добавить строку в таблицу базы данных(допусти, Таблицу1)?

В WindowForms я добавлял строку к элементу управления, заполнял, и записывал (update dataset), а в WPF прошу помощи разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Практически тоже самое, что и в WinForms

[Пошаговое руководство. Привязка элементов управления WPF к набору данных](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd547149.aspx#Y2700)

[Привязка WPF к таблице данных](http://www.intuit.ru/department/se/prcsharp08/15/) [ADO.NET](http://ADO.NET)

[Создание приложений доступа к данным с помощью WPF](http://www.techdays.ru/videos/1311.html)

[Работа с набором данных в WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples)